# How to type in a label on runtime (vb.net)?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want at runtime to click on my label and change its text, how to do that?

```
Private Sub BapAra_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyPress
        Label1.Text &= e.KeyChar
    End Sub
```

Comment: With an asp.net webforms, you’ll have the best experience with JavaScript

Comment: you included asp.net, which suggests and means web based systems. If your question is not about web development, then remove that asp.net tag here. asp.net (web based) labels do NOT have a server side click event. You can wire up a JavaScript click event, but that would be browser side based code. however, it not clear if you question is about desktop development, or web based development. Answers in regards to web based development will be VAST different then answers for desktop development. so, if you answer yes here in comment about web based, then I can and will post some sample web code.

Comment: You could style a text input control to look like a label, but how would the user know it was editable?

Comment: So you're asking how to make a `Label` behave like a `TextBox`. Maybe use a `TextBox` instead. If you really wanted to use a `Label` then the appropriate UX would be to right-click and then edit in a dialogue, using a `TextBox`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a TextBox with an invisible border instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to change the text when the label is Clicked, your event should occur on the BUTTON-NAME-ONCLICK() event and not on the keypress event...